# Magento - how do I show in the Order Email the Customer ID?

Tags: php, magento

I want to show the customer ID in the order confirmation emails.

I know I have to add a variable into the email template something along the lines of :

```
{{var customer.id}}
```

But that example doesn't work. I have searched and it doesn't seem to be one of the default variables so how can I do this?

Comment: You can pass variables into the Magento email models, e.g. in your controller/model that triggers the email `$template->send('email@here.com', 'email@here.com', $variables);` and `$variables = array('customer_id' => Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getId())` (example only) then in your email template you could just use `{{var customer_id}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other who may need,you can use this:

```
{{var order.getCustomerId()}}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as correct. I tested it and it does exactly what I asked for (I no longer need this but hopefully it will be usefful for someone else and it has also just helped with add teh account email into the sale emails instead of just the payment email that it includes as standard which sometimes can be different -. ie if paid by paypal the email is often different to the account email -  this works for the account email  {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}